# Finding the value of $r$ such that the ratio of $^{3}P_{r}$ ​and $^4P_{r−1}$ will be $\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find the value of $r$ such that the ratio of $^{3}P_{r}$
​ and $^4P_{r−1}$ will be $\dfrac{1}{2}$? Can anyone please answer this.

$^{3}P_{r}$ and $^4P_{r−1}$ == $P(3, r)$ and $P(4, r-1)$

$^nP_{r} = 
\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}$

If I consider $r=1$ $=>$  $^{3}P_{1} = 3 $ and $^4P_{r−1} =$ $^4P_{0}$ $=>$ $1$

$ r = 1$ is not resolving to $\frac{1}{2}$

If I consider $r=2$ $=>$  $^{3}P_{2} = 6 $ and $^4P_{r−1} =$ $^4P_{1}$ $=>$ $4$

$ r = 2$ is also not resolving to $\frac{1}{2}$

If I consider $r=3$ $=>$  $^{3}P_{2} = 6 $ and $^4P_{r−1} =$ $^4P_{2}$ $=>$ $12$

$ r = 3$ does resolve to $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation, what is the meaning of $\phantom{}^3 P_r$?

Comment: @Abbas It is not. ${}^nC_r$ is different from ${}^nP_r$. It is called ["Permutation"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

Comment: @yooo Thank you for correcting.

Comment: What have you tried btw?

Comment: With the upper indices being so low, it shouldn't be too difficult to find out !

Comment: Try writing these as factorials and then cancel as much as you can

Comment: You have tried $r=1$ and $2$. What happens with $3$ or $4$ or $0$?

Comment: @Henry $r = 3$ resolves to $\frac{1}{2}$ - thank you.

Comment: @Henry $r$ cannot be equal to $0$ as ${}^4P_{r-1}$ will be undefined if $r = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\boxed{{}^nP_r = \frac{n! }{(n-r)!}}$$

Just apply the formula in LHS of the equation $\frac{{}^3P_r}{{}^4P_{r-1}} = \frac12$ and simplify it. You will get the value of $r$.

Can you take it from here?